# Why do we need to put self as the argument while calling another class function

Tags: python

I understand that while defining functions we have to use self as the first argument but in my particular coding example for insert_node method I got an error while calling insert_node(node,new_node) saying 3 arguments expected when I did not use self as the first argument in insert_node

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
class BST:
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.root = Node(value)
    def insert(self,value):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = Node(value)
            return
        curr = self.root
        new_node = Node(value)
        def insert_node(self,node,new_node):
            if node.value == new_node.value:
                return
            if node.value > new_node.value:
                if node.left is None:
                    node.left = new_node
                    return
                else:
                    insert_node(self,node.left,new_node)
            else:
                if node.right is None:
                    node.right = new_node
                    return
                else:
                    insert_node(self,node.right,new_node)
        insert_node(self,curr,new_node)
```

Comment: Is that the actual indentation? `insert_node` isn't an instance method, it's a nested function *inside* one.

Comment: `insert_node()` is not a method, it is a function nested inside `insert()`.

Answer (score 4):

`insert_node()` is not a method, it is a function nested inside `insert()`. You don't need to use `self` in this function, at all, because it makes no use of that argument, and even if it did, it could access the `self` reference from the parent `insert()` method as a closure.

Removing the `self` argument altogether works:

```
class BST:
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.root = Node(value)

    def insert(self,value):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = Node(value)
            return
        curr = self.root
        new_node = Node(value)

        def insert_node(node, new_node):
            if node.value == new_node.value:
                return
            if node.value > new_node.value:
                if node.left is None:
                    node.left = new_node
                    return
                else:
                    insert_node(node.left, new_node)
            else:
                if node.right is None:
                    node.right = new_node
                    return
                else:
                    insert_node(node.right, new_node)

        insert_node(curr, new_node)
```

You can move that function *out* of the `insert()` method too, it doesn't need to be nested there:

```
def insert_node(node, new_node):
    if node.value == new_node.value:
        return
    if node.value > new_node.value:
        if node.left is None:
            node.left = new_node
            return
        else:
            insert_node(node.left, new_node)
    else:
        if node.right is None:
            node.right = new_node
            return
        else:
            insert_node(node.right, new_node)

class BST:
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.root = Node(value)

    def insert(self,value):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = Node(value)
            return
        curr = self.root
        new_node = Node(value)
        insert_node(curr, new_node)
```

However, this really should be a method *on the `Node` class*:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert_node(self, new_node):
        if self.value == new_node.value:
            return
        if self.value > new_node.value:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = new_node
                return
            else:
                self.left.insert_node(new_node)
        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = new_node
                return
            else:
                self.right.insert_node(new_node)

class BST:
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.root = Node(value)

    def insert(self,value):
        if self.root == None:
            self.root = Node(value)
            return
        curr = self.root
        new_node = Node(value)
        curr.insert_node(new_node)
```

Because you access `insert_node()` on `Node` instances (via `curr.insert_node(...)`, `self.left.insert_node(...)` and `self.right.insert_node(...)`, it is bound to that instance for you by Python, and passed into the method as `self`.

Comment: Thanks, should I not use nested functions when I just want the call to be internal to a class method?

Comment: @vkaul11: no, not really. Python has no privacy model, it expects programmers to be responsible instead. You can name the function `_insert_node` if you want to flag it as API private, but that's no more than a convention.

Comment: @vkaul11: use nested functions when you need access to a closure, not to hide things.

Comment: You mean only function closures?

Comment: @vkaul11: there are no other kind in Python, not sure what you are asking?